# Should I keep training samples without labels

Tags: dataset, object-detection

I want to supervisely train an object detector for pedestrians, this detector is expected to ideally detect all the pedestrians in an image, and output the detected pedestrians as 2D bounding boxes, so that we can know where the pedestrians are in the image.

So this is a common object detection problem, and I plan to use KITTI 2D object dataset to train this pedestrian detector.

The KITTI 2D object dataset has 8 classes labels, such as 'Car', 'Pedestrain', 'Van'. All I need are pedestrian labels to train this detector, but there are images that don't contain any pedestrains.

My question is, should I include the images without pedestrains into my train dataset? Should I evaluation my model on test images without pedestrains? Is there a default or widely accepted handling method?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification is an option, like the https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-class-classification-algorithms/ or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05365.pdf regards, shibamouli

Comment: Do you mean you want to train your model to tell the difference between images that do contain pedestrians and images that do not? In that case, yes, yes you do need to include images without pedestrians in your training data. One-class classification, mentioned in the answer below, is possible, but not sensible if you do have images without pedestrians since it's much less accurate.

Comment: @Eoin ,@ShibamouliLahiri ,  thanks for the replies, I want to train a pedestrian detector that can ideally detect all the pedestrians in an image, so it is not a One-class classification problem, I clarified it in the question description